# What's wrong with this code in java that uses FileReader?

Tags: java, file-io, filereader

I have been trying to learn about `FileReader` and hence wanted to test it out. I created a class whose constructor takes in a string(name of the file) and creates a file and then reads from it and then prints the first character out, but my code is not working and is showing errors. This is my java code.

```
package test_3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Files {
    public Files(String s) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File f = new File(s);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        System.out.println(fr.read());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException,   IOException{
        Files myFile = new Files("input.txt");
    }
}
```

This is the error information

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test_3.Files.<init>(Files.java:11)
    at test_3.Files.main(Files.java:16)
```

Comment: *The system cannot find the file specified*. So the file `"input.txt"` is not present in the same directory as the class `Files`. Where is the file located?

Comment: Also: when it does work, you'll want to close `fr` after you use it - and you'll probably find that the output from `System.out.println(fr.read());` is not what you expect (it will be an integer, not a character).

Comment: @Tunaki The directory where the class Files is located has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java FileReader cant find file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641167/java-filereader-cant-find-file)

Comment: @Kainix I tried, but I can't do it for the first 10 minutes after the question was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the file cannot be found. What you should do is get the path to where java is looking for the file, like so.

```
System.out.print(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

And then place "input.txt" within that directory (the directory that is printed when that code is ran).

Alternatively, use the full absolute path to input.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot. I put my file one level inside the path that I actually had to and hence I was getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: Yes did it, thanks. I was not able to do it initially because of the site's time limits.